# make available of accessing to full path and reloading page with react-router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I use react-router in my react project.
This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app on browser",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build",
    "start": "cordova run browser"
  },
  "author": "maki",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "history": "^4.2.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^2.2.3",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.4",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-motion": "^0.4.4",
    "react-router": "^2.7.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.7.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.13.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I have a router like below:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="/news" component={NewsPage}/>
      <Route path="/news/:id" components={News}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
    <Route path="/member" component={MemberPage}/>
    <Route path="/products" component={ProductsPage}/>
    <Route path="/contact" component={ContactPage}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Here is what I want to achieve:
1: Access to except IndexRoute.
　ex) http://example.com/news/1234
2: Making available of reload except IndexRoute page.

Now, I try that, and I receive this message:

> Cannot GET /news

what should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the history fallback for browserify in your gulpfile similar to this:

```
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

// ...
browserSync({
  server: {
    baseDir: './',
    middleware: [historyApiFallback()],
  },
});
```

Comment: but, when I did so, I receive an error message: "Cannot GET /"

Comment: Check if if the `baseDir` is the path to where your `index.html` is.